# Prevent Sentry.io from logging server error codes

Tags: angular, logging, sentry

I have an Angular application using Sentry.io for logging. I created a custom error handler class where I initialise Sentry and I would like to avoid log server errors (404 Not Found or 500 Server Error).

I read that if a Network call fails in Angular, the exception is bubbled up and not catched in the ErrorHandler (hence it would not trigger `handleError` method).

However even if I use the `beforeSend()` method, as suggested to face this very specific case, the console logs are written (eg. SENTRY SKIPPING EVENT), but all the server errors keep being logged in Sentry.

```
export class MyhErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    if (environment.production) {

      Sentry.init({
        dsn: 'https://12314567@sentry.io/123456789',
        environment: this.environmentData.env,
        beforeSend(event) {
          try {
            if (this.isServerError(JSON.stringify(event))) {
              console.log('------   SENTRY SKIPPING EVENT: ', {event});
              return null;
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('------   SENTRY ERROR: ', {e});
          }
          return event;
        }
      });
    }

   handleError(err: any): void {
     if (!this.isServerError(err)) {    
       const errorText = MyhErrorHandler.getError(err);
       Sentry.captureException(errorText);
     }
   }

  private isServerError(error: any): boolean {
    if (!error) {
      return false;
    }

    const regex = new RegExp(
      `500 Internal Server Error|401 Unauthorized|403 Forbidden|404 Not Found|502 Bad Gateway|503 Service Unavailable`,
      'mi'
    );

      return regex.test(JSON.stringify(error);
    } catch (error) {
      Sentry.captureException(`Error in myh-error-handler while parsing error Obj: ${errorText} -- ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to my problem and I write it here so it might help others.

I used the property `ignoreErrors` accepting a string or a RegEx during the Sentry the initialisation:

```
const serverErrorsRegex = new RegExp(
      `500 Internal Server Error|401 Unauthorized|403 Forbidden|404 Not Found|502 Bad Gateway|503 Service Unavailable`,
      'mi'
    );

 Sentry.init({
        dsn: 'https://123456@sentry.io/12345678',
        environment: this.environmentData.env,

        // We ignore Server Errors. We have to define here since Angular 
        // http client uses setTimeout to detect http call progress.
        // And when the call fails, it throws an exception inside that timeout 
        // that bubbles up higher to the main Angular's error handler.
        ignoreErrors: [serverErrorsRegex]
      });
```

In the Regex I used the flags `mi` standing for:

- 'm': multiline mode
- 'i': case insensitive

More details about [Regex flags here](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction).

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks, what's the "mi" exclusion (apologies, it is late I could be missing something obvious!)

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer with the description, in case others might have the same doubts.